# box model extra pixels width

Tags: css, layout, width

Thank you for reading this

I'm having an odd problem with layouts. I've used Meyer's CSS reset. I have a div containing 3 divs as follows. I've not added any content yet.

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="gallery"></div>
  <div class="gallery"></div>
  <div class="gallery"></div>
</div>
```

The following styles are applied

```
#container{
  width: 954px;
}

.gallery {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 270px;
  margin: 24px;
}
```

So in my mind each gallery is 24px + 270px + 24px = 318px wide. The combined width of the 3 gallery divs is therefore 318px * 3 = 954px.

However the divs will only display across a single row when I increase the width of #container to 960px.

Where are the 6 mystery pixels coming from? I've double checked all other border, margin and padding values are 0. I've even set outline to 0px although this shouldn't have an effect either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner divs are set to `display: inline-block;`. This means that any white-space between them will result in a single space added between them in the layout.

**Option 1**

While not a pleasant solution, you will not see the extra space if you do this.

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="gallery"></div><!--
  --><div class="gallery"></div><!--
  --><div class="gallery"></div>
</div>
```

**Option 2**

Another solution that is unpleasant for different reasons, is to set `font-size: 0;` on the `#container`. If you intend to have text inside, you will need to set the `font-size` of the elements inside to a pixel value.

```
#container{
  width: 954px;
  font-size: 0;
}

.gallery {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 270px;
  margin: 24px;
}
```

**Option 3**

The cleanest solution however would probably be to float the inner divs left, and clear-fix the wrapper.

```
#container{
  width: 954px;
}

#container:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.gallery {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 270px;
  margin: 24px;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks so much. I never would have considered white space. In this case im going to go with <!-- -->

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to "nowrap" the white-space?

Comment: That fixes the symtoms. I never knew the white-space attribute existed. However it doesnt help me understand the cause. Thank you all the same though